# How do I create a constructor that initializes coordinates to random values?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have this class "Point" which takes in x and y as arguments.
However I need to create a constructor that initializes them to random values.
I don't know exactly how it is done. Here's my code:
I created constructors but I'm getting values that are absurd even when I set x and y.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

    using namespace std;
    class Point
    {
    private:
        double x;
        double y;

    public:

        double get_x()
        {
            return x;
        }
        void set_x (double x)
        {
            this->x = x;
        }
        double get_y()
        {
            return y;
        }
        void set_y(double y)
        {
            this->y = y;
        }
        double distanceTo(Point p)
        {
            double x2 = p.get_x();
            double y2 = p.get_y();
            return sqrt( pow(x-x2,2) + pow(y-y2,2) );
        }
        Point(double x, double y)
        {
            x = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
            y = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
        }
        Point(){};


    };

    void main()
    {
        Point a(1.2,0.5);
        Point b;
        b.set_x(1);
        b.set_y(1);
        cout << a.distanceTo(b);
        system ("Pause");
    }
```

Comment: don't name arguments of methods the same as members of the class. It's confusing and error prone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Mistake:* You changing local copies of variables passed to constructor by value (they have same name as member variables) and member variables left uninitialized so your program has undefined behavior.

*How to fix:* You must explicitly indicate what variable you are assigning to. Also, overload you constructor, so you will have one (default) for random values, and one for user-predefined.

*Also:*

- it's better to pass values that *not going to be changed* in function as *constant*
- you might want pass `double` *by reference*, *not by value*
- use *initializers lists* instead of assignment in constructor body
- when using constant references here you don't need to resolve names because you can't change constant values, so compiler will change member variables

*Code:*

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point() : 
        x(rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100), 
        y(rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100)
    {

    }

    Point(const double& x, const double& y) :
        x(x), 
        y(x)
    {

    }

private:
    double x, y;

};


int main()
{
    Point pt(42, 3.14);
    Point pt_random;
}
```

Same in accessor functions:

```
    double GetX() const { return x; }
    void SetX(const double& x) { Point::x = x; }
```

Comment: *SIGH*, could you just copy/paste my code and edit. I'm sorry I don't understand what you are trying to tell me, because I tried it and its still giving me values  like 1.633e+0.234

Answer (score 4):

That's because you aren't initializing your member variables, but changing a copy of the variables that are being passed into the constructor. Hence you're seeing garbage values as `x` and `y` (the class versions) are never initialized. You should change this to:

```
Point()
{
    x = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
    y = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
}
```

Further, you never call `srand()` anywhere - you need to do this at some point to properly seed the random generator.

Comment: so what exactly should I change? I changed my intialization to what you wrote, I got
"'Point::Point' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Because you're altering temporary variables in the constructor (name collision in the same scope). Try:

```
Point(double x, double y)
{
  Point::x = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
  Point::y = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
}
```

But that completely disregards arguments given to the constructor. But since now you know how to differentiate between different scopes of variables, you can go on from here, I believe.

Comment: @pmr - I don't know. I tend to prefer this syntax. Doesn't this add performance penalnty (dereferencing)? I know it could be optimised away by the compiler, but you're never sure of this.

Comment: Interesting point. I never really thought about it in terms of performance. Definitely worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your default constructor does nothing. It doesn't even initialize the values which means they are going to have an unspecified value.

Your constructor taking two arguments just assigns to the arguments, because their names shadow the names of the members.

Comment: I don't understand what I should change in order to achieve what I mentioned in the post...Please feel free to edit my code

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Point(){};
```

to

```
Point()
{
    x = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
    y = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
}
```

also I would advice to change your arguments\members name to avoid mistakes. I personally like to use `m_` for members :

```
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 'name collision'. In this function

```
    Point(double x, double y)
    {
        x = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
        y = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
    }
```

The compiler is doesn't know which x you mean when you assign. The language rules will say that the input arguments should be assigned - but you should not rely on this - because it is needlessly confusing.

A good practice is to adopt a naming convention for member variables. Two common ones are to prefix members with "m" or "_". I like "m" personally.

Then your code becomes:

```
class Point
{
   public:
      double mX;
      double mY;

   Point(double x, double y)
    {
        mX = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
        mY = rand()*1.0 / RAND_MAX  * 100;
    }
}
```

Also the constructor arguments in this case are redundant, and can be removed.

Some of the other answers above are also correct - but it is a sign of bad class design if you have to explicity scope names ( e.g. Point:: ) in simple functions.